# Google app engine: ndb sort property

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have the following model:

```
class Product(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    bidTime = ndb.DateTimeProperty()
    price = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    ...
```

I'd likd to use the following query:

```
productRanks = Product.query(Product.bidTime>=startDate,
                             Product.bidTime<endDate).order(-Product.price).fetch()
```

where `startDate` and `endDate` are datetime objects. But I got the following error message:

*The first sort property must be the same as the property to which the inequality filter is applied*

If I add `Product.bidTime` in the order then there will be no error:

```
.order(Product.bidTime, -Product.price)
```

However, the sorted result would be wrong (according to date, not price). So, what is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no problem as far as appengine is concerned.  It is behaving as documented.  From the docs

> Note: Because of the way the App Engine Datastore executes queries, if
>   a query specifies inequality filters on a property and sort orders on
>   other properties, the property used in the inequality filters must be
>   ordered before the other properties.

See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries#Sort_Orders

You may need to sort in memory after you get your result set.

Comment: Thanks. So I have to implement a sorting algorithm myself (e.g., Bubble sort ;-). That's too bad.

Comment: Umm no you don't have to implement your own sort algorithm, though you can if you don't want to read the docs ;-).  Assuming your result set is not enormous just use python's inbuilt sorting capabilities. Remember if you do a fetch() on the result set you get a list back.  Even if it's an enormous set use the facilities that are already available to you.  Here is a good starting point for sorting in python. http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/